# Using include_once in a jquery dialog modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dialog

Trying pull include_once to pull from a list of template pages based on the data.

```
 $("#dialog").dialog({
    resizable: true,
    open: include_once 'application/views/templates/item_changed_modal.php',
    width: 'auto',
```

This is how I'm implementing it in. Going to eventually have the "item_changed_modal" to changed dynamically based on the data that its going to display. For now just hardcoding in a test page.

Can include_once be used in this fashion?

Comment: Try using `open: <?php include_once 'application/views/templates/item_changed_modal.php'; ?>,` see if that will work.

Comment: Do as Fred says, you are mixing php code with javascript code, which is good as long you declare you are going to do so, simply wrapping the php code in <?php ... CODE HERE... ?> would do.

Comment: The `open` property specifies a callback, so it should be a function. Also, it looks like you're mixing php and javascript. Remember that php executes on the server _first_, and javascript executes on the client later. What you're probably going to need to do is replace the content of the `#dialog` div. You could fetch the content using ajax.